# How to determine that negative values are imutable when using a lookup table in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, lookup

I'm using a lookup table to replace the values of my matrix `b` according to an `a` array. My data is populated with a negative value (-9999) to represent "no data" for my final analysis. Because of the inverted index, my output matrix is not what I was expecting (see out: -9999 turns to 22). Is there any way to determine that the negative value remains imutable? If I only use positive values, the code works fine, but that's not my case =/. Thanks in advance!!

```
a = np.asarray([[1, 11], [2, 22], [3, 33], [10000, 555]], dtype=np.int32)
b = np.asarray([[0, 1, 2, 3, -9999], [0, 1, 2, 10000, -9999], [0, 1, 2, 3, -9999], [0, 1, 2, 3, -9999]])
lut = np.arange(b.max()+1) #look up table
#creating equation to result in output
k,v = a.T
lut[k] = v
out_matrix = lut[b]
```

outputs:

```
ref table...
[[    1    11]
 [    2    22]
 [    3    33]
 [10000   555]]

lookup table...
[    0     1     2 ...,  9998  9999 10000] 

matrix to change...
[[    0     1     2     3 -9999]
 [    0     1     2 10000 -9999]
 [    0     1     2     3 -9999]
 [    0     1     2     3 -9999]]

out_matrix...
[[  0  11  22  33  22]
 [  0  11  22 555  22]
 [  0  11  22  33  22]
 [  0  11  22  33  22]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the required number (9999) of dummies at the end of your lut. Then [-9999] will reference the first of these dummies and you can set it at whatever you like.

```
NV = -9999
a = np.asarray([[1, 11], [2, 22], [3, 33], [10000, 555]], dtype=np.int32)
b = np.asarray([[0, 1, 2, 3, -9999], [0, 1, 2, 10000, -9999], [0, 1, 2, 3, -9999], [0, 1, 2, 3, -9999]])
lut = np.arange(b.max()+1-NV) #look up table
lut[NV] = NV
#creating equation to result in output
k,v = a.T
lut[k] = v
out_matrix = lut[b]

out_matrix
# array([[    0,    11,    22,    33, -9999],
#        [    0,    11,    22,   555, -9999],
#        [    0,    11,    22,    33, -9999],
#        [    0,    11,    22,    33, -9999]])
```

If you are concerned about the memory wasted you can use stride_tricks like so:

```
NV = -9999
a = np.asarray([[1, 11], [2, 22], [3, 33], [10000, 555]], dtype=np.int32)
b = np.asarray([[0, 1, 2, 3, -9999], [0, 1, 2, 10000, -9999], [0, 1, 2, 3, -9999], [0, 1, 2, 3, -9999]])
lut = np.arange(b.max()+2) #look up table
lut[-1] = NV
lut = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(lut, (lut.size-1-NV,), lut.strides)
#creating equation to result in output
k,v = a.T
lut[k] = v
out_matrix = lut[b]

out_matrix
# array([[    0,    11,    22,    33, -9999],
#        [    0,    11,    22,   555, -9999],
#        [    0,    11,    22,    33, -9999],
#        [    0,    11,    22,    33, -9999]])
```

**Warning:** Used improperly this can let you try accessing out-of-bounds memory. You must make sure to never reference anything other than 0 ... max(b) or NV.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

Since you need to allow all other indexes to work normally, just use [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)
EDIT: @Paul Panzer points out however that this fails if -9999 is not a valid index for lookup.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.asarray([[1, 11], [2, 22], [3, 33], [10000, 555]], dtype=np.int32)
b = np.asarray([[0, 1, 2, 3, -9999], [0, 1, 2, 10000, -9999], [0, 1, 2, 3, -9999], [0, 1, 2, 3, -9999]])
lut = np.arange(b.max()+1) #look up table
#creating equation to result in output
k,v = a.T
lut[k] = v
out_matrix = np.where(b!=-9999,lut[b],-9999)
```

Output:

```
array([[    0,    11,    22,    33, -9999],
       [    0,    11,    22,   555, -9999],
       [    0,    11,    22,    33, -9999],
       [    0,    11,    22,    33, -9999]])
```

Solution 2:

If finesse won't do, some trickery surely can do the trick. Utilize the lookup table to create an additional lookup. Wrap in a function if you need to perform this operation multiple times.

```
import numpy as np

def masked_lookup(lut, lookup_array, mask_value = -9999):
    '''Performs a lookup for all values except a mask_value, 
     set to -9999 by default. Uses Array indexing and points
     the masked value to itself in the lookup. '''
    lut_with_mask = np.zeros(len(lut) + 1, dtype=np.int32)
    lut_with_mask[:-1] = lut
    lut_with_mask[-1] = mask_value
    lookup_array[lookup_array == mask_value] = len(lut)
    return lut_with_mask[lookup_array]

a = np.asarray([[1, 11], [2, 22], [3, 33], [1000, 555]], dtype=np.int32)
b = np.asarray([[0, 1, 2, 3, -9999], [0, 1, 2, 1000, -9999], [0, 1, 2, 3, -9999], [0, 1, 2, 3, -9999]])
max_value = b.max()
lut = np.arange(max_value + 1) #look up table
#creating equation to result in output
k,v = a.T
lut[k] = v
out_matrix = masked_lookup(lut, b)
```

Output:

```
array([[    0,    11,    22,    33, -9999],
       [    0,    11,    22,   555, -9999],
       [    0,    11,    22,    33, -9999],
       [    0,    11,    22,    33, -9999]])
```

Comment: This will not work if the lut is too small. To see this, replace both occurrences of `10000` in the example with `1000`.